# Xpath 1.0: if condition true, then do this => combine these 2 xpaths

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xpath-1.0

I have already prepared 3 xpaths (v1.0) who are doing their correct task, but I have to combine them in 1 code (nesting).

1
Check if this is true: `contains(substring($tmpVariable, 10, 2), '^[A-Z]+$')`
if YES, then

2

```
concat(substring($tmpVariable, 1, 10), ' ', substring($tmpVariable, 11), '   0000000')
```

and in very best way (if possible) a kind of else statement (=step 3).

3

```
concat(substring($tmpVariable, 1, 11), '    0000000')
```

Hope this is possible in xpath 1.0 and if somebody would like to help a dummy.

Comment: Is this in the context of a XSLT transformation?

Comment: no, pure xpath nesting.

Comment: I'm still struggling with ==> contains(substring($tmpVariable, 11, 1), '^[A-Z]+$') and contains(substring($tmpVariable, 12, 1), '^[A-Z]+$'), the 11th and 12th character should be checked if they are letters, no numbers. I have the impression that the syntax does not work perfectly even when there is no error at all of my system (read: syntax is correct, but result is not correct)
Any ideas?

Comment: Please do not add relevant information in comments, edit your question instead. Also, please add the actual XML input document. If this is "pure XPath", please remove the XSLT tag.

Comment: you can try removing the '^', '+' and  '$' since the string length will be always 1, and you can include lower case letters as well

Comment: @gjspaho: your suggestion gives the same result. The letters are always in capitals, so I see no reason to add small letters too in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out - found searching something similar some time ago

http://dreamix.eu/blog/java/xml-java/how-to-create-if-else-statement-in-xpath-1-0

EDIT: to follow mandatory answer rules i'm adding the comment to the answer

if C1 then R1 else R2 ==> concat(substring(R1, 1, number(C1)*string-length(R1)), substring(R2, 1, number(not(C1))*string-length(R2)))

replace the C1, R1, R2 by your existing xpaths

Comment: Fan-tas-tic! Tip for newbies like me: code is as follows => if C1 then R1 else R2 (this is for better understanding) ==> code is as follow (just replace the C1, R1, R2 by your working existing xpaths ==> concat(substring(R1, 1, number(C1)*string-length(R1)), substring(R2, 1, number(not(C1))*string-length(R2)))

Answer (score 0):

This one is simple. You can try having a look the the below link.

Hope that helps!

[The Oliver Becker's XPath method](http://blog.alessio.marchetti.name/post/2011/02/12/the-Oliver-Becker-s-XPath-method)

Here is the sample from this link -

concat(

substring('FOO', number(not(condition_for_foo))*4),
 substring('BAZZ', number(not(condition_for_bazz))*5)
)

Comment: Please actually answer the question in your post. Just a link is not going to help people much if for example the link is broken over time.